# How can I speed this vba code up which involves formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a new pricing schedule which reads selected information from a 'Register' tab, based on selected criteria, and copying this into a new tab. This data is formatted so it looks aesthetically pleasing.
I am finding formatting the code is slowing down the run speed significantly. If possible I would like to speed this up as I will be iterating this multiple times.

I hae sped the program up a reasonable amount. Initially it took 30s, whereas now it is about 10s.
I have followed information from this website as best as I can:
https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx

I feel there is still scope to improve more, though I am unsure how, and am reaching out to see if there is, or are, better ways to improve the code so it runs quicker.

```
Option Explicit
Sub create_pricing_schedule()

'define workbook variables
Dim Start_Time As Double, End_Time As Double
Dim file1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim namedRange1 As Range
Dim namedRange2 As Range
Set file1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = file1.Worksheets("Pricing Schedule")
Set ws3 = file1.Worksheets("Control")
Set ws4 = file1.Worksheets("Register")
Set namedRange1 = file1.Names("Client_Register").RefersToRange
Set namedRange2 = file1.Names("Pricing_Range").RefersToRange

'define general variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim collect(1 To 500, 1 To 10) As Variant
Dim rw As Range
Dim selectedClient As String
Dim lastrow As Integer, lastrow2 As Integer, lastrow3 As Integer

i = 1

'time how long it takes to improve efficiency
Start_Time = Timer

'speedup so less lagg
Call speedup

'delete everything from the pricing schedule/reset
With Sheets("Pricing Schedule")
    .UsedRange.ClearContents
    .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    .Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .Cells.MergeCells = False
    .Range("A:Z").WrapText = False
    .Rows.RowHeight = "15"
End With

'resize the client register
lastrow = ws4.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveWorkbook.Names("Client_Register")
    .RefersTo = "=Register!$A$1:$AE$" & lastrow
End With

selectedClient = ws3.Range("B3").Value
'copy from database to the pricing schedule as a non formatted list of all the info - this runs quickly, but I am open to changing it
For Each rw In Range("Client_Register").Rows
    If Range("Client_Register").Cells(rw.Row, 2) = selectedClient Then
        collect(i, 1) = Range("Client_Register").Range("E" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 2) = Range("Client_Register").Range("D" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 3) = Range("Client_Register").Range("F" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 4) = Range("Client_Register").Range("J" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 5) = Range("Client_Register").Range("K" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 6) = Range("Client_Register").Range("L" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 7) = Range("Client_Register").Range("M" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 8) = Range("Client_Register").Range("P" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 9) = Range("Client_Register").Range("I" & rw.Row)
        collect(i, 10) = Range("Client_Register").Range("H" & rw.Row) ' used to determine if pass through fee

        ws2.Range("B" & i + 6) = collect(i, 1)
        ws2.Range("C" & i + 6) = collect(i, 2)
        ws2.Range("D" & i + 6) = collect(i, 3)
        ws2.Range("E" & i + 6) = collect(i, 4)
        ws2.Range("F" & i + 6) = collect(i, 5)
        ws2.Range("G" & i + 6) = collect(i, 6)
        ws2.Range("H" & i + 6) = collect(i, 7)
        ws2.Range("I" & i + 6) = collect(i, 8)
        ws2.Range("J" & i + 6) = collect(i, 9)
        ws2.Range("K" & i + 6) = collect(i, 10)

        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

'add in the colour and count how many rows there are
lastrow2 = ws2.Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveWorkbook.Names("Pricing_Range")
    .RefersTo = "='Pricing Schedule'!$A$1:$K$" & lastrow2
End With

ws2.Range("B7" & ":" & "J" & lastrow2).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)

'==========this bit is slow, can it be quicker?==========
'add spacing, titles, and colour to sub headers
i = 7
For Each rw In Range("Pricing_Range").Rows
    If Range("Pricing_Range").Cells(i, 3) <> Range("Pricing_Range").Cells(i + 1, 3) Then
        Range("Pricing_Range").Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        Range("Pricing_Range").Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        Range("Pricing_Range").Rows(i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Range("Pricing_Range").Rows(i + 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

        Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B" & i + 2 & ":" & "J" & i + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 128, 1)
        Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B" & i + 2 & ":" & "J" & i + 2).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B" & i + 2 & ":" & "J" & i + 2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B" & i + 2).Value = Range("Pricing_Range").Range("C" & i + 3).Value

        'if it is a pass through fee then add it in to the sub headers
        If Range("Pricing_Range").Range("K" & i + 3).Value = "Pass-Through" Then
            Range("Pricing_Range").Range("J" & i + 2).Value = "Pass-Through Fees"
            Range("Pricing_Range").Range("J" & i + 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End If
        i = i + 3

        Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
'==================================================

'set up the main title rows
ws2.Select
Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B2").Value = ws3.Range("B3").Value
Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B2").Font.Size = 20
Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B2").Font.Bold = True
Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B2").Font.FontStyle = "Calibri Light"
Range("Pricing_Range").Range("B2:J3").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .MergeCells = True
    .Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 128, 1)
    .Cells.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Cells.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End With

'tidy up things in the sheet
With Worksheets("Pricing Schedule")
'set up the headers and first title
    .Range("B6") = .Range("C7")
    .Range("B5:J6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 128, 1)
    .Range("B5:J5").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Range("B5:J5").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Range("B6:J6").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Range("B6:J6").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Range("B5").Value = "Fee Code"
    .Range("C5").Value = "Product Line"
    .Range("D5").Value = "Item"
    .Range("E5").Value = "Volume From"
    .Range("F5").Value = "Volume To"
    .Range("G5").Value = "Frequency"
    .Range("H5").Value = "Location"
    .Range("I5").Value = "Price"
    .Range("J5").Value = "Nature of Fee"

'tidy up column widths
    .Range("A5").RowHeight = 30
    .Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 2
    .Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 15
    .Range("C1").ColumnWidth = 40
    .Range("D1").ColumnWidth = 45
    .Range("E1").ColumnWidth = 11
    .Range("F1").ColumnWidth = 11
    .Range("G1").ColumnWidth = 35
    .Range("H1").ColumnWidth = 15
    .Range("I1").ColumnWidth = 12
    .Range("J1").ColumnWidth = 50
    .Range("J:J").WrapText = True
    .Range("K:K").Delete
End With

'clear the extra orange line at the end
lastrow3 = ws2.Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Row
With ws2.Rows(lastrow3 + 2)
    .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    .Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    .ClearContents
End With

'add print area
With Worksheets("Pricing Schedule")
    .PageSetup.Zoom = False
    .PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$J$" & lastrow3
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
    .PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$2:$6"
End With

'return to normal
Call slowdown

'time how long it takes to improve efficiency
End_Time = Timer
Worksheets("Control").Cells(6, 2) = End_Time - Start_Time
End Sub

Sub speedup()
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

End Sub

Sub slowdown()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [codereview.se] is the place for getting help with refactoring working code.

Comment: Im happy for you to do so. I did not know code review existed and it seems the right place to go

Comment: @KenY-N In the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close questions. Evaluate the request & use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Flag it for Mod intervention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750/1575353). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I'd vote for more use of With blocks (main benefit would be readability), and assigning cell values as blocks from arrays instead of cell-by-cell (better performance).

Comment: @TimWilliams How would i go about doing it in blocks? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few lines that could save you some execution time.

```
'****EDIT****Changed this to direct range reference rather than go through the Names collection.
'Set namedRange1 = file1.Names("Client_Register").RefersToRange
'Set namedRange2 = file1.Names("Pricing_Range").RefersToRange
Set namedRange1 = file1.Range("Client_Register")
Set namedRange2 = file1.Range("Pricing_Range")
```

**Used range takes more time rather use .cells directly**

```
'delete everything from the pricing schedule/reset
'****EDIT***
With ws2 'Sheets("Pricing Schedule")
    'used range takes more time rather use .cells directly
    .Cells.ClearContents
```

**Rather than use arrays you can directly update values as shown below**

```
'I am using i for the row count
        ws2.Range("B" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 5).Value
        ws2.Range("C" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        ws2.Range("D" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 6).Value
        ws2.Range("E" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 10).Value
        ws2.Range("F" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 11).Value
        ws2.Range("G" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 12).Value
        ws2.Range("H" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 12).Value
        ws2.Range("I" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 16).Value
        ws2.Range("J" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 9).Value
        ws2.Range("K" & i + 6).Value = namedRange1.Cells(i, 8).Value
        i = i + 1
```

**The main culprit for your slower performance is the insert operation**. try to work the logic to not having insert. If not possible, try to insert rows outside the loop in a single operation rather than in the loop

```
        Range("Pricing_Range").Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        Range("Pricing_Range").Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I found the last issue to bethe biggest one. I added in a line on the 'array' part to say if the line category is the same as the one below, do 1+2. This way I dont need to insert any lines. I had to re-engineer some stuff later on but it only takes 3s now, rather than 10. so big improvement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your handling of the collect array is inefficient. Consider reading the entire Client Register into an array with MyArray = Range.Value. Then prepare the output array in memory and write it to the worksheet after all looping is done, in one go, with TargetRange.Value = collect.

Avoid inserting rows. What's wrong with the existing? If you are preparing all data in an array to be pasted to the worksheet, empty array elements will produce empty worksheet cells. In this way all inserting can be avoided and all you need to do is to format.

There is time cost for every access to the worksheet, whether to read or write. Even for formatting, try to create ranges that are treated in the same manner. Avoid accessing the worksheet in loops.

Comment: is it possible to format outside of accessing the worksheet?

Comment: No, formatting must be applied to the worksheet range. But it's faster to apply a format to a group of cells than to format each cell individually like happens in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Example of With and block assignment from an array:

```
'copy from database to the pricing schedule as a 
'   non formatted list of all the info - this runs quickly, 
'   but I am open to changing it
With Range("Client_Register")

    For Each rw In .Rows
        If .Cells(rw.Row, 2) = selectedClient Then

            collect(i, 1) = .Range("E" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 2) = .Range("D" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 3) = .Range("F" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 4) = .Range("J" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 5) = .Range("K" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 6) = .Range("L" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 7) = .Range("M" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 8) = .Range("P" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 9) = .Range("I" & rw.Row)
            collect(i, 10) = .Range("H" & rw.Row)

            'you could even skip the row-by-row population of values
            '  and assign as a block after exiting the loop
            ws2.Range("B" & i + 6).Resize(1, 10).Value = _
                    Array(collect(i, 1), collect(i, 2), collect(i, 3), _
                          collect(i, 4), collect(i, 5), collect(i, 6), _
                          collect(i, 7), collect(i, 8), collect(i, 9), _
                          collect(i, 10))

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

End With
```

Note this will break if your `Client_Register` refers to a range which doesn't start on Row1, because of the relative range references.

Eg:

```
 Range("A1:A10").Range("A1") 'refers to A1
 Range("A2:A10").Range("A1") 'refers to A2
```